# How to stop DIVS from moving about when zooming in or out of a page?

Tags: css, html, zooming

Noob to HTML and CSS. I've created what I believe to be a pretty decent webpage. However, I made the whole page using the same laptop, so when I viewed it on a different computer the whole layout was different. When I zoom in or out of a page it changes the position of my `div`s, so if the zoom isn't perfect then my webpage looks ridiculous.

Here is my HTML & CSS:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("glass.jpg");
    width:100%;
    }

    h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left: 450px;
    color: #e41b17;
    font-size: 34pt;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 580;
    z-index: 90;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px black;
    font-size:50pt;
    }

    h3 {
    position:relative;
    top:18px;
    left: 490px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 34pt;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 580;
    z-index: 70;
    font-size:40pt;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
    }
    
    article.ben {
    text-indent: 20px;
    text-align:justify;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:17px;
    }

    #bodybuilding{
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: #3b5998; 
    color: white;
    font-size: 34pt;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 580;
    border:groove;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0.6em;
    border-radius: 15px;
    }

    #bodybuilding span {
    color:#e41b17;
    }

    img.lats {
    float:left;
    border: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    }

    img.bicep {
    position:absolute;
    top:143px;
    right:300px;
    float:left;
    border: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    }

    .wrapper {
    width:800px;
    height:1950px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#EDEFF4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    } 


    aside.sidebar1 {
    position: Absolute;
    Top:300px;
    Right:70px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family:Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    }

    H4 {
    font-size: 22pt;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #e41b17
    }


    .links {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#EDEFF4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1600px; 
    left:90px;
    text-align:center;
    text-color:black;
    }

    #more {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:  #e41b17;
    } 

    #mm {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    }

    footer {
    margin:15px;
    width:800px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#EDEFF4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    right:253;
    }
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    
    <title> Gordon's News </title>

    </head>

    <header>

    <h1 class="top"><a href="index.html"> Gordon's News </a> </h1>
    <h3>Gordon's News </h3>

    </header>


    <body> 

    <div class="wrapper">


    <h2 id="bodybuilding">THE TESTOSTERONE FUELLED  BODYBUILDING</h2>


    <article class="ben">


    <figure>

    <img class="lats" src="lat.jpg" alt="front lateral spread pose" 
    <img class="bicep" src= "bicep.jpg" alt="bicep" height="150" width="100">
    </figure>

    <p>Every morning he wakes up, ....

    (I wont bore you will the whole article)

    </article>

    </div>


    <nav class="links">

    <h4 id="more">More stories</strong></h6>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://news.sky.com/story/1101193/steroids-put... </a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/17/business... </a></li>
    </ul>

    </nav>


     <Aside class= "sidebar1">

    it's a <ul> basically

    </aside>


    <footer>
    <p><strong> <a href="index.html">Home </a></strong> </P>
    </footer>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I really do not understand why they move about when zooming.

Comment: You are still confuse on positioning, read through css static, relative, fixed, absolute, and sticky properties, but I suggest you use bootstrap, makes everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are working with properties like:

```
position:absolute;
top;
left;
right;
float;
```

And many of the elements with those properties has no parent container or not relative then his parent is the whole body of the page. When you work with values to position you need to be carefull with the related object to make the position work.

Now if you have for example an absolute position in relation to the body like:

```
left:100px;
```

The element always going to be at 100 px of the body no matter resolution screen or size window.

You may need to look in detail your code and set relative parents and keep in mind the real fixed structure to make it solid.